# Wallet injection to dapps

Tags: wallets, ethereum-wallet-dapp, connections

I have a react-native wallet application and I'm trying to achieve automatic wallet connection to dapps when a dapp is rendered from a react-native web-view.

1. Are there any implementations available for the same ?
2. How does coinbase and metamask achieve this ?

[react-native-webview](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-webview)

I know that there are EIPs [1193](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1193) and [6963](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-6963) for this, but I'm unable to inject javascript successfully to achieve this as the web-view is only expecting injected javascript in string. I'm facing difficulties to stringify the provider without losing any of its functionalities like request, send etc.